# I'm trying to use I2C with beaglebone but I cannot write more than 1 byte

Tags: linux, i2c, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to control DAC5571 with Beaglebone Black. My kernel version is:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.14.108-ti-r137 #1stretch SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 25 01:48:39 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I can partially the control the DAC IC. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK83d.png), you need to send 3 bytes; Slave Address, CTRL/MSB and LSB. The IC recognizes Slave address bytes and CTRL/MSB. I can read and confirm the output of the output pin. But when I start increasing the voltage value slowly as Vout += 0.05, output increasing as 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, etc...

I've checked with my oscilloscope and I can confirm that the third byte is being transmitted as 0x00 no matter what its the actual value is.

Here is my source code:

```cpp
int DAC5571::writeI2CDeviceByte(int value)
{

  cout << "Starting DAC5571 I2C sensor state write" << endl;

  char namebuf[MAX_BUS];
  snprintf(namebuf, sizeof(namebuf), "/dev/i2c-%d", I2CBus);
  int file;

  if ((file = open(namebuf, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        cout << "Failed to open DAC5571 Sensor on " << namebuf << " I2C Bus" << endl;
        return(1);
  }

  if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, I2CAddress) < 0) {
        cout << "I2C_SLAVE address " << I2CAddress << " failed..." << endl;
        return(2);
  }

  int buffer[2];

    buffer[0] = value>>8;
    buffer[1] = value & 0xFF;

    cout << "buffer [0] is " << buffer[0] << endl;
    cout << "buffer [1] is " << buffer[1] << endl;
  if (write(file, buffer, 2) != 2) {
      cout << "Failure to write values to I2C Device address." << endl;
      return(3);
  }
  close(file);
  cout << "Finished DAC5571 I2C sensor state write" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
Starting DAC5571 I2C sensor state write
buffer [0] is 3
buffer [1] is 128
Finished DAC5571 I2C sensor state write
```

I've seen on my research there is a header file called as "i2c-core.h" but I could not include into my projects which has a block write function. Not sure if that would help in my situation.

Can anyone please help me to solve my issue about not being able to transmit LSB part of the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = value>>8;
    buffer[1] = value & 0xFF;
    if ( write(file, buffer, 2) != 2) { ... }
```

The elements of `buffer` are of type `int`, which is 4 bytes long.  So when you write `buffer` with a length of `2`, you write 2 bytes, which are the first two bytes of the integer `buffer[0]`.  In your example `buffer[0]` is `3`, so since this machine is little-endian, it consists of the bytes `03 00 00 00` and you write out `03 00`.

You probably want `unsigned char buffer[2];` or maybe `uint8_t buffer[2];`, so that each element is a byte.

Comment: Thank you Nate, changing it to ```char buffer``` solved the issue.

Comment: I guess the `put_unaligned_be16()` (or rather `cpu_to_be16()` with `__be16 buffer;`)  is less error prone and gives less LOCs as well.

Comment: Okay, it seems the user space program, so for the future, there is `libi2c` from `i2c-tools` which helps with all this.